# Caminho invertido, percorrer caminho para trás

Tags: string, path

olá. eu tenho tentado saber se posso inverter um caminho?

como posso reverter um caminho e depois seguir normalmente? por exemplo eu preciso de reverter um caminho para esta string ( LPCWSTR path = ) entao preciso voltar umas pastas atras e depois seguir o caminho normal

exemplo

normal

```
LPCWSTR path = (L"C:\\pasta1\\texto.txt");
```

Sentido Inverso

```
LPCWSTR path = (L"C://Pasta2// \\aqui continua normal \\pasta1\\texto.txt");
```

na pasta2 eu preciso recuar e a pastir da pasta1 eu preciso continuar normalmente.

como faço isso?

Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para voltar um diretório `../`

`../../` volta dois diretórios.

Comment: Obrigado. Funciona. e se eu quiser andar mais diretórios segue-se o mesmo certo?

Comment: isso, `/` avança diretório; mesmo diretório `./`; retrocede `../`

Comment: Quem diria que fosse tão fácil assim. Obrigado pela resposta rápida.